react recharts pie chart custom style
I developed an half donut pie chart but i could not add red circle to the point 2 pies touch each other
I need to add a red circle white bordered in pic below.
this is my component
import {
  PieChart,
  Pie,
  Sector,
  Cell,
  ResponsiveContainer,
  Label,
} from "recharts";

function Gauge() {
  const data = [
    { name: "Group A", value: 400 },
    { name: "Group B", value: 200 },
  ];
  const percentage = (
    (data[0].value / (data[0].value + data[1].value)) *
    100
  ).toFixed(0);
  const COLORS = ["#E8333E", "#F7B9BD"];
  const startAngle = 180; 
  const endAngle = 0; 
  const totalValue = data.reduce((acc, item) => acc + item.value, 0);
  const firstSegmentValue = data[0].value;
  const firstSegmentPercentage = firstSegmentValue / totalValue;
  const firstSegmentEndAngle = startAngle - (startAngle - endAngle) * firstSegmentPercentage;
  const midpointAngle = firstSegmentEndAngle - (firstSegmentEndAngle - endAngle) / 2;
  const radius = 70;

  // Calculate position for the circle
  const cx = 100 + radius * Math.cos(midpointAngle * Math.PI / 180);
  const cy = 100 - radius * Math.sin(midpointAngle * Math.PI / 180);
  return (
    <PieChart width={800} height={400}>
      <Pie
        data={data}
        cx={100}
        cy={100}
        startAngle={180}
        endAngle={0}
        innerRadius={60}
        outerRadius={80}
        fill="#8884d8"
        paddingAngle={0}
        dataKey="value"
        cornerRadius={6}
      >
        {data.map((entry, index) => (
          <Cell key={`cell-${index}`} fill={COLORS[index % COLORS.length]} />
        ))}
        <Label
          value={`${percentage}%`}
          position="center"
          style={{ fontSize: "30px", fontWeight: "700" }}
        />
      </Pie>
      <circle
        cx={cx}
        cy={cy}
        r={6}
        fill="#E8333E"
        stroke="white"
        strokeWidth="3"
      />
    </PieChart>
  );
}

export default Gauge;

I tried to use <circle> but could not calculate its x and y values. circle places a point out of context
this is the current case

this is what i wanna have

